# Copy compiled sibling .jar file into directory

Tags: java, gradle

I have a gradle project which, for testing purposes, needs to have a jar file in a specific directory at runtime.

This jar file needs to be compiled from a sibling project.

How would I go about acheiving this? Complete noob at gradle here.

To clarify, I don't need project A to depend on project B, I need project B to be compiled and have its .jar file copied into a directory inside project A.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I need project B to be compiled and have its .jar file copied into a directory inside project A.

Although I think it's the best way to do it, you can use a custom task to do that for you

```
task copyB(type: Copy) {
    from './B/build/libs/B.Jar'
    into '.'
}
tasks.named("copyB") { finalizedBy("buildBJar") }

task buildBJar(type: Exec) {
    workingDir '.\\B'
    commandLine("cmd", "/c", "gradle", "build")
        doLast {
            println "B has been built and now JAR will be copied"
        }
    }
}
tasks.named("build") { finalizedBy("copyB") }
```

This will do the following :

- When you trigger build at project `A`, It will need to execute `copyB` task before it will execute the build
- And as another rule, `copyB` task is related to `buildBJar` and will wait for execution.
- at this point, `buildBJar` will be executed, Then `copyB` then project's `A` build will be triggered after the `B` jar has been transferred to your desired location.